# Service Implementation - how to choose which service implementation will be used based on application.properties attribute?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, service

I have two service implementations:

**Service interface:**

```java
/** 
* Service used for resolving external ID for the entity.
*/
public interface ResolveService {
   String valueToResolve(String id);
}
```

Implementation of Service - A:

```java
@Service
public class ResolveServiceAImpl implements {

  @Override
  public String valueToResolve(String id) {
    // grpc impl...
  }

}
```

Implementation of Service - B:

```java
@Service
public class ResolveServiceBImpl implements {

  @Override
  public String valueToResolve(String id) {
    // jpa impl...
  }

}
```

For now, this is resolved with `@Qualifier` and this implementation works:

```java
   @Qualifier("resolveServiceBImpl")
   @Autowired
   private ResolveService resolveService;
```

The problem for me is that I don't want to define in every class String value of @Qualifier. I would like to define @Qualifier value in one place, let's say in application.properties file.

**application.properties:**

```
resolve.service.active=resolveServiceBImpl
```

This implementation is not working:

```java
   @Value("'${resolve.service.active}')")
   private String resolveServiceActive;

   @Qualifier(resolveServiceActive)
   @Autowired
   private ResolveService resolveService;
```

The error I am getting is `Attribute value must be constant. Cannot find bean with qualifier null.`

Is there any other way how to resolve @Qualifier value, so that I need to assign it manually in every class separately?

Comment: Could you use profiles for this? It seems like you're reinventing something Spring already has.

Answer (score 4):

@jonrsharpe tnx for answer.

I resolved it with a `@Profile`.

SOLUTION:

**Service A Implementation:**

```java
@Service
@Profile("A")
public class ResolveServiceAImpl implements ResolveService {...
```

**Service B Implementation:**

```java
@Service
@Profile("B")
public class ResolveServiceBImpl implements ResolveService {...
```

and application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=A
```

And for the test I used `@ActiveProfiles("A")`.

This solved my problem.